# How to publish WCF service in internet (hosted in wnd service)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows service on my laptop, which hosts a WCF service. I would like to use these service on my ASP.NET website, which is on external ASP.NET server.

Could you help me, how to do this?

Is it necessary a specific laptop configuration for that? What should I configure?

And binding, what type will adequate? .. Right now, I've got:

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServices.InfoBehavior" name="MyProgram.WcfServices.Info.Info">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyProgram.WcfServices.Info.IInfo">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Info/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

UPDATE:
Right now, my client app is still on my laptop (it is not publish yet).. This is my client code:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Info/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IInfo" contract="ServiceInfo.IInfo"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IInfo">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

I don't know, what binding use.. what port, what settings should be changed on my laptop?

Comment: I don't think is a good idea, if the LapTop is off or disconnected the ASP.NET web site will still work well? Anyway, from your binding probably this is not the best: localhost:8732 and in fact you should show the client configuration not the server. Show us how you are referencing the laptop's service from the ASP.NET web.config file

Comment: well, web aplication only show some info about running windows service. When wnd service is stopped, there is a note about that on web. This is my personal web, not a public portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your laptop has its own fixed IP address exposed externally (most unlikely) I think you will find it hard to do this directly.

You might consider using Azure Service Bus to broker message exchanges: I believe this is one way to solve the problem of accessing a service hosted on a non-constant IP address or behind a firewall/NAT.

Or you could consider changing your design to turn things the other way around. That is, when it is connected and running, your laptop service connects to a service hosted on the ASP.NET box, over a duplex binding, with your current service contract as the callback contract.

Comment: But If I have a static, external IP is it possible? I mean, one more time, On one machine I've got a windows service, with WCF hosted. And on the other I've got an ASP.NET web page, with WCF client.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, of course, if you really do have a static external IP. Use that IP address in the configured service URL both ends, and whetever port you like (within reason). You'll need to make sure your laptop's inbound firewall has that port open, and you might also need to check that the hosting environment doesn't have any outbound firewall rules which will stop your requests leaving the web server.

Comment: So, Correct my if I'm wrong please. To access WCF Service hosted in Windows service on my laptop from an external ASP.NET page somewhere in the Internet I need: 1. External static IP on my laptop 2. Configure outbound and inbound rules. And by 2) I mean: Start->Run->WF.msc->Inbound Rules->New Rule->Port->TCP + Specifi local ports 5500->Allow the connection->Domain + Private + Public->Name MyWCF... and Outbound Rules the same as Inbound... this right? And finally baseAddress and clients endpoint address will be: "http://87.xxx.xxx.xxx:5500/Info/". Is that all?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WCF service running on your laptop hosted via `ServiceHost` you'll need to duplicate that configuration in your ASP.NET web.config file, as well as add a "service.svc" file which is referenced to the Interface of your service.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `localhost` with real external facing IP address of your laptop and it could work if your router at home has no firewall. Change it in both client and server endpoint address.

Comment: But Is it impossible with firewall? I mean, without firewall, my machine is not secured, right? so it's not a good solution I think..